# How To use AsyncTask in multiple class? it is giving null pointer exception 

Tags: android, android-asynctask

m Very new on android and this is my first Query on Stackoverflow.
here is i am getting null pointer exception while using AsyncTask.
I am using ProgressDialog, for that i had created a (seperate (new)) class which extends AsynchTask. when i pass the argument to the class from my main class from where i want to show ProgressDialog it gives me a nullpointer exception..
can any one tell me what to do..
here is code

```
class Loader extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public void setDialog(ProgressDialog dialog){
        this.dialog = dialog;
    //here i get the reference of dialog from the caller class

}
```

Thanks in advance..
Mahaveer

Comment: Are you using Loader as inner class

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to send the dialog as a parameter to your `AsyncTask`, probably this causes your error. You can create a new `ProgressDialog` inside your `AsyncTask` and show it in `onPreExecute` method, since this method is running on UI thread. Hope this helps.

P.S. Try to always post a logcat of your error if you got one, this will make it easier for people to help. And congratulations on your first post!

Answer (score 0):

Use overridden onPreExecute method instead of setDialog

Answer (score 0):

```
private class LocationControl extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>
{
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Tap outside dialog to close");
        this.dialog.setTitle("Searching your current location...");
        //this.dialog.setTitle(R.string.hello);
        this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params)
    {
        //Wait 40 seconds to see if we can get a location from either network or GPS, otherwise stop
        Long t = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        while (!hasLocation && Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - t < 40000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused)
    {
        if(this.dialog.isShowing())
        {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (currentLocation != null)
        {
            GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(currentLocation.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(currentLocation.getLongitude()*1E6));
            final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.animateTo(startPoint);
            mc.setZoom(16);
        }
        else
        {
            /*
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location could not be found\nusing default location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(43.332628*1E6),(int)(5.353128*1E6));           
            final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.animateTo(startPoint);
            mc.setZoom(16);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

And call the execute from your `onCreate()`:

```
locationControlTask = new LocationControl();
locationControlTask.execute(this);
```